# problems with scapy, can't import by * and can't run the script

Tags: python, scapy

can't import all modules
can't run the code

I'm trying to run this simple script

```
from scapy.all import *

# Create an IP packet
ip_packet = IP(src="192.168.1.1", dst="192.168.1.2")

# Create a TCP segment
tcp_segment = TCP(sport=1234, dport=80, flags="S", seq=1000)

# Combine the IP packet and TCP segment
packet = ip_packet / tcp_segment

# Send the packet to the destination host
send(packet)
```

**1.** Despite the import at the top of the code, it does not recognize the IP and TCP methods

**2.** When I run the code (I replaced the asterisk with the specific modules I need), I got an error related to the socket:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shlomo/PycharmProjects/stbot/test_radio.py", line 13, in <module>
    send(packet)
  File "venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 445, in send
    return _send(
           ^^^^^^
  File "venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 414, in _send
    socket = socket or _func(iface)(iface=iface, **kargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 484, in __init__
    self.ins = socket.socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 232, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**I Would appreciate your help**

Comment: The problem is not linked to your import.  Sending raw packets requires administrator privileges (e.g., being root on linux). This is what the `PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permit` means. Besides, the error message says that the error is raised at line 13 of the code (`send(packet)`), so this means that previous lines creating IP and TCP layers work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your program using 'sudo' command will solve your problem.

[using 'sudo' permission on kali linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgyLi.png)

```
sudo python network_scanner.py -t 10.0.2.1/24
```